# List all RSYNCed folders in GCP GAE Linux

Tags: linux, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I set up some folders in GAE to be synced using the command -

```
gsutil rsync -r gs://sample1bucket1 ./sample1;
```

But I have forgotten what all places I have done it. How to list all these?

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding of your question, all your GAE folders are in cloud storage bucket, “sample1 bucket1”, and you are trying to sync them into directory “sample1”.If yes, then while writing the rsync commands you have to mention source and destination. So you should know where you are syncing all your files to, as per [public documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/rsync#synopsis).

However,

> you can list the folders in the current directory using the “ ls “
> command  to check for your destination folder and later cd into those
> folders “cd simple1” (for your case) to see if the content has been
> copied from your bucket to the file.

> You can also list the number of running rsync processes using :

```
ps -ef| grep rsync | wc -l
```

I am leaving some information regarding the commands, in case you need them :

> You can list all objects in a bucket using :

```
gsutil ls -r gs://bucket
```

> You can list the directory with detailed information using :

```
rsync --list-only username@servername:/directoryname
```

> You can list the folder contents using :

```
 rsync --list-only username@servername:/directoryname/
```

> You can also use the following command to parse out exactly what you need :

```
rsync -i
```